# Who exactly is the subscriber of an Xcode Playground Publisher?

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to better understand the Combine framework. AFAIK, `.sink()` connects a publisher to a subscriber. In an Xcode Playground page, who exactly is the subscriber? Consider the following example:

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsInfiniteExecution = true

var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

Timer.TimerPublisher(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common)
    .autoconnect()
    .sink { print($0) }    // Who is this sink connecting the timer publisher to?
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

I know the pub-sub link is taking place because the publisher does indeed start publishing. It is just unclear who the subscriber is. Is there a way to deterministically query Combine for who the subscriber is?

Also, if the subscriber of this timer publisher is the playgroundPage's current instance, then why do I have to store the subscription using `store(in:)`? Shouldn't this be unnecessary since the subscriber is not going out of scope any time soon (not until I stop the playground)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong. `.sink` is a subscriber — actually, it creates a [Sink object](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/subscribers/sink), which is a subscriber — and in this case, it is *the* subscriber.

An added fine point is that an operator, such as `.autoconnect()`, is both a subscriber and a publisher. But there is only one true subscriber at the end of this pipeline, and it is the Sink.

The Sink does not "connect the timer publisher" to anything. It itself is the object that is printing.

The `.store` command assigns the Sink (wrapped up as an AnyCancellable) into the `subscriptions` set. Note that this is a bad name: in Combine, a subscription is a very, very different thing from a subscriber.

Comment: It might help you to read my online tutorial: https://www.apeth.com/UnderstandingCombine/

Comment: Thanks for answering my question! My updated understanding based on this answer is that using this publisher chain, we are creating a subscriber and storing it in a set so that we have a strong reference to it and thus it does not get prematurely deallocated. The only thing I am surprised about is why `subscriptions` would be a misnomer in this situation; Ray Wenderlich's Combine book names all its `Set<AnyCancellable>` objects `subscriptions`. Anyhow, I will most certainly give your tutorial a good look!! If you have a few seconds to expand on here why subscriptions is a misnomer I'm all ears